# How to add a backlash (\) at the beginning and the end of a string in Python

Tags: python, string, concatenation

I'm trying to add a backlash symbol ( \ ) at the beginning and the end of a string in Python. When using the code listed bellow, everything at the right of the equal symbol becomes green on my development environment (Eclipse) and I get an error message.

```
mystring = "\" + mystring + "\"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Use a double slash (`'\\'`) instead of a single one:](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html)

Original:

```
>>> print "\hello\"
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print "\hello\"
                  ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Double:

```
>>> print "\\hello\\"
\hello\
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

see the page, https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

escapeseq : "\"  + any ASCII character

```
mystring = "\\mystring\\"
```